# One regex for tag with multiple parameters and replacement

Tags: php, regex

```
[tag]foobar[/tag]
[tag parameter1]foobar[/tag]
[tag parameter2="whatever"]foobar[/tag]
[tag parameter1 parameter2="whatever"]foobar[/tag]
[tag parameter2="whatever" parameter1]foobar[/tag]
```

Can I match all these combinations in one expression? Ideally suitable for additional parameters. I tried a few things but nothing works. For now i am going to match every single combination but i guess, that's not the best.

The second matter, i want to make a replacement for the parameters.

`parameter1` to `class="tagclass"`

`parameter2="input"` to `id="input"`

Is it possible to do it all in one step?

Thanks and regards,
Alex

Comment: As far as I know, this can definitely be done. I'm not that adept at Regexp, so I can't make up an example ( it would literally take me hours :) ), but I do know, that this can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has code that does that:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/shortcodes.php

It doesn't work 100%, but it gets the job done. See in particular the `shortcode_parse_atts()` function (line 225 as I write, but subject to change in later versions of WP).

Comment: oh great! there is a shortcode API for wordpress (http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). Are you a medium or how did you know i need that for wordpress ;) However, thanks a lot!

Comment: I had absolutely no idea you were using WP, but the syntax was that of WP shortcodes so I figured I'd highlight it... :-)